# How to disable trace.jtl for JMeter + Tauras execution

Tags: jmeter

We are running JMX using Tauras setup. To run a lightweight test we need to disable all logging.

I tried by adding:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      log_level.jmeter: 'FATAL_ERROR'
      logging:
        level:
            ROOT: 'ERROR'
      Log_Level: 'DEBUG'
```

We still see the `trace.jtl` file with log information. Can anyone help us with how to disable logging to `trace.jtl` file?

Do we have any specific command in Tauras to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `trace.jtl` is controllable by these properties, what you change controls the verbosity of [JMeter Logging subsystem](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/), to wit the contents of *jmeter.log* file under the artifacts directory.

`trace.jtl` is a different beast, it contains request/response details provided by adding yet another [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) configured like:

[image]

So if you want to get rid of it - locate the [`write-xml-jtl` line](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Test-Log) in your configuration script and comment it (or remove it or set it to something different than `full` or `error`), on next execution you won't see this `trace.jtl` file

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, it worked by setting write-xml-jtl=none.